# Remake button method to call from constructor or any event

Tags: c#, windows-8, event-handling, windows-store-apps

Is there any way how I can  call method  img_Tapped without tap(not when I click on UI element(button))but call it for example from constructor? I have handler to MessageReceived. If no anyone can advise how I can remake these two methods for the same function - I dont need click element these method should be performed when is app started or page loaded ...

method 1:

```
private async void img_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...

        mws = new MessageWebSocket();
        mws.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Binary;

        mws.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;

        await mws.ConnectAsync(server);
        messageWriter = new DataWriter(mws.OutputStream);
        messageWriter.WriteBytes(buff);
        await messageWriter.StoreAsync();
    }
```

method 2:

```
 private void MessageReceived(MessageWebSocket sender, MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DataReader reader = args.GetDataReader())
            {
                reader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
                byte[] read = reader.ReadBuffer(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength).ToArray();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

.
.
.

I find this but its not good because click/tap on button is still needed and I dont want it.

```
img.Tapped += new TappedEventHandler(my method with button parameters);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just call the method directly? `img_Tapped(null, new TappedRoutedEventArgs())` (or something similar). It feels like your design may need rethinking, but without more context its hard to say.

Comment: no its not design error. I use this code from microsoft sample and working great but they call it when click on button but I need these method call from constructor and I dont know how rework parameters.(

Comment: In your constructor, If you don't use the `e` parameter then you can try to call img_Tapped() method like this: `img_Tapped(this, null);`

Comment: ok thx img_Tapped(null, new TappedRoutedEventArgs()) work and img_Tapped(this, null)  too thx